# Setting Billing and Shipping address for Quote

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, shipping-address

I am trying to set the Billing and Shipping address for the Quote extracted from the Order like this,

```
$quote->setBillingAddress($order->getBillingAddress());
$quote->setShippingAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
```

But the address is picked up in the quote hence the order is not created on Magento

The following are the messages gathered from the logs

```
ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::setBillingAddress() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address, instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address given, called in app/code/localXmlConnect/controllers/CheckoutController.php and defined  in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php

ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::setShippingAddress() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address, instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address given, called in app/code/local/XmlConnect/controllers/CheckoutController.php and defined  in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have override checkout controller right?